# How to create a new seller (store) under administrator using drupal commerce marketplace

Tags: commerce

I am using drupal commerce kickstart to create an eCommerce portal. I need to create sellers, re-sellers and sub-re sellers with in the site. i had installed commerce marketplace, but not aware of creating the new seller. Please help.

The hierarchy will be

The Service Provider has multiple resellers, each reseller can have multiple sub-resellers and finally end-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you add role like seller then just add a user with role of seller and set permission for seller.

Comment: Do commerce marketplace comes with a built in role seller with all the functionalists of a seller.

Comment: No we have to add role 'seller',then set permission for marketplace seller

Comment: http://zgadzaj.com/commerce-marketplace-installation-and-use-cases

Comment: Ok Thanks. I had created an admin (Seller),   user (Re-Seller) and a product. How can i assign this re-seller under seller (admin). I need to assign the new product to the re-seller.